# SQL Server 2008 transactional replication-Snapshot .NET error

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server-2008, replication

I've setup a transactional replication (my first time) but the SQL Server Agent Job used for first snapshot keeps failing with this error:

> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "sp_scriptdropinsreconciliationproc_sqlclr":
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' threw an exception.
>   ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory' threw an exception. 
>   ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlPerformanceCounters' threw an exception. 
>   ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize
>   ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Config\machine.config' is denied. (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Config\machine.config)
>   ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727

I've checked the access to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Config\machine.config` is fine, even double-checked by enabling auditing and confirmed.

I've also seen that a KB2840628 could create .NET issues but I don't have it installed on my server.

My environment is SQL Server 2008 running on Windows Server 2008 R2. Replication is all configured on the same server between two DBs

Comment: What account is the job running under?

Comment: SQL Agent service account, the issue has been fixed by restarting SQL services.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with windows Authentication or change the snapshot agent run step from -DistributorSecurityMode , to -DistributorSecurityMode 0.